# Will SOAP web services work with Spring Security as it does with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-security

Can I use `Spring Security` to wrap my Http SOAP Web Services as it does with `Spring MVC`?

If so, is this does in the same way with `@RolesAllowed` and this class?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        //...
    }

}
```